# I am not able to send/receive messages with public IP in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am not able to send/receive messages with public IP in Kafka. I tried by changing IP with private and public. I also tried by changing `advertised.host.name` to 0.0.0.0.

What am I missing in Kafka ?

Comment: Which IP address did you change, the server or client, or both? Please provide more details on your network setup in working and non-working situation. And why did you change advertised host name to 0.0.0.0? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please can you provide more information about how you're running Kafka, and where you're trying to access it from? You will also find this relevant: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: thanks for your quick reply @wovano . i'm find out the issue where is missed, i added the private IP in /etc/hosts.  now  able to receive messages from Kafka server.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are running Kafka on one machine and trying to access it from other machine.

It can be debugged as follows:

1. Try pinging the public IP from your machine. `ping public_ip`
2. If ping works, then try doing a `telnet` to that public IP along with the Kafka bootstrap server port.
   For example, `telnet 1.2.3.4 9092`

If you are able to telnet means, that you are able to connect to the public IP (here, 1.2.3.4) and port from your machine.

If you are not able to connect, check your *iptables* rules on your Kafka server. You may want to allow the port to be accessible from outside.

Example to allow 9092 port.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9092 -j ACCEPT
```

3. You may also want to check if any firewall is blocking access like UFW or firewalld. Try disabling them or allow Kafka port there and check.
4. If you are using OpenStack or similar software, you may want to check Security group rules there and allow those ports. This can be applicable to AWS also.
5. Check that your `advertised.listeners` have the public IP which you are using to connect to. By default this property is found in `etc/kafka/server.properties` file.

Change it to something like (if you are using `PLAINTEXT`)

`advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<PUBLIC_IP>:<PORT>`

For example,

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://1.2.3.4:9092
```

`advertised.host.name` seems to be DEPRECATED now ([see documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html))